# Applying wsp solution file to Sharepoint site collection programmatically

Tags: site-collection, content-database, content

I am trying to deploy a sitecollection with a content database attached to each site collection.  I was able to deploy site collections with individual content databases for each sitecollection, unfortunately when I try to access the site collection, I get an Access Denied Notification.  Even if I try to log in with the highest account, I am unable to log in.  I am thinking it is because the sitecollection does not have a proper template attached or used when creating the site.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how do I add a wsp file to a sitecollection that is being created?

Comment: Please post the exact code or script that you're having an issue with or it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Refer following link might be helpful for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528516.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether you are the site collection administrator or not. That can be checked through central admin, even if that also is access denied, then you can check from the below script:

```
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("$your siteurl")
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication 
foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{    
   foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)    
        {        Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"    
        }    
   $site.Dispose()
}
$rootSite.Dispose()
```

Similarly you can use powershell script to deploy the wsps. The wsp will be deployed either globally or to the web application.

Use below script to deploy wsp:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity <SolutionName> -WebApplication <URLname>
```

◦`<SolutionName>` is the name of the solution.

◦`<URLname>` is the URL of the Web application to which you want to deploy the imported solution

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

WSPs aren't deployed to site collections but either globally or to Web Application.

If you want to deploy WSPs to Web Applications then you can use the [Deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439404.aspx) method of SPSolution

Comment: Don't forget user solutions. A user solution will be deployed in the site collection.